# preg_replace : capturing single quote inside single quote escaped expression

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

In a wordpress theme, I am using the "posts_where" filter to add search to the "excerpt" field. It is working excepted when there is a single quote in the search string, leading to a SQL synthax error.

It seems to be a bug in the preg_replace function off the posts_where filter.

For example, for the string "o'kine" , the $where string received in the posts_where filter is :

```
"AND (((cn_posts.post_title LIKE '%o\'kine%') OR (cn_posts.post_content LIKE '%o\'kine%')))"
```

Then this is my preg_replace to add the post_excerpt field :

```
$where = preg_replace(
"/post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')/",
"post_title LIKE $1) OR (post_excerpt LIKE $1", $where );
```

And the value of the $where after :

```
"AND (((cn_posts.post_title LIKE '%o\') OR (post_excerpt LIKE '%o\'kine%') OR (cn_posts.post_content LIKE '%o\'kine%')))"
```

See the '%o\' part that is causing the SQL synthax error.

The expected result would be :

```
"AND (((cn_posts.post_title LIKE '%o\'kine%') OR (post_excerpt LIKE '%o\'kine%') OR (cn_posts.post_content LIKE '%o\'kine%')))"
```

The bug is clearly in my regular expression, more precisely in my capturing parentheses. I do not know how to deal with the possibility of zero or more single quote in my search string?

EDIT : With Casimir et Hippolyte answer, this is the working filter with single quote in the search string :

```
function cn_search_where( $where ) {

    $where = preg_replace(
    "/post_title\s+LIKE\s*('[^'\\\\]*+(?s:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*+')/",
    "post_title LIKE $1) OR (post_excerpt LIKE $1", $where );

    return $where;
}
```

Comment: Please clearly and concisely share input and expected output as well as current output (if any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subpattern to match a quoted string with eventual escaped quotes (or other characters) is:

```
'[^'\\]*+(?s:\\.[^'\\]*)*+'
```

*(note that to figure a literal backslash in a regex pattern, it must be escaped since the backslash is a special character)*

So in a php string (backslashes need to be escaped one more time):

```
$pattern = "~'[^'\\\\]*+(?s:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*+'~";
```

With this information, I think you can build the pattern yourself.

details:

```
'        # a literal single quote
[^'\\]*+ # zero or more characters that are not a single quote or a backslash
(?s:     # open a non-capture group with the s modifier (the dot can match newlines)
    \\.      # an escaped character
    [^'\\]*  
)*+      # repeat the group zero or more times
'
```